# Read from text file and store them into a linked list in c

Tags: c, queue, file-read

i have these methods :

```
void loadQueue(nodePtr *start, nodePtr *end) 
{
CreateQueue(&start, &end);
int c;
FILE* file = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Queue.txt", "r");
int numbers[50];

int i = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{   
    numbers[i] = atoi(&c);
    i++;
}


for (int j = 0; j < i ;j++)
{

    Enqueue(j, &start, &end);

}
};
```

Now i want to use this method to make them in a queue :

```
nodePtr CreateNode(int num) {
nodePtr p = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node)); // ALLOCATE MEMORY TO ONE NODE AND SET P TO POINT TO IT

if (p != NULL) // REMEMBER always check if memory was allocated otherwise the behaviousog program is undefined :)
{
    p->item = num;
    p->next = NULL;
}
return p;
```

}

and the create node is used in this method :

```
bool Enqueue(int item, nodePtr *start, nodePtr *end) {
nodePtr newitem = CreateNode(item);
if (newitem != NULL)
{
    if (isEmptyQueue(*start))
    {
        *start = newitem;
    }
    else 
    {
        (*end)->next = newitem;

    }

    *end = newitem;
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}

};
```

Can someone tell me how I can store the data passed (numbers) that I read in the enqueue as I am trying to do in the loadQueue method.

Comment: What kind of data do you use? Add example

Comment: `numbers[i] = atoi(&c);` Probably bad.

Comment: in the queue.txt there  is "123456"

Comment: On an unrelated note, functions are not terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Not really helping, but you should check the return value of `fopen`

Comment: Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are two many unknowns to be able to help you.

Comment: `Enqueue(j, &start, &end);` type mismatch.

Comment: `Enqueue(j, &start, &end);` --> maybe `Enqueue(numbers[j], start, end);`

Comment: nope :/ .. thx for the help

Comment: it works :) I had to change the CreateQueue parameters to (start, end)  as well thank you! :D

Comment: the function `atoi()` expects a pointer to a NUL terminated string, not a pointer to a single character.

Comment: When calling `fopen()`, always check(!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc)  The returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.. indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: the variable `c` is already an integer, so this line: `numbers[i] = atoi(&c);` is not correct.  Suggest: `numbers[i] = c;`

Comment: what is the definition of `nodePtr`?

Comment: this line: `Enqueue(j, &start, &end);` will generate a queue that contains the contents of `j`.  I suspect you really want to generate a queue that contains the contents of the array `numbers[]`, Suggest: `Enqueue( numbers[j], &start, &end );`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
void loadQueue(nodePtr *start, nodePtr *end) 
{
CreateQueue(start, end);
int c;
FILE* file = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Queue.txt", "r");
int numbers[50];

int i = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{   
    numbers[i] = atoi(&c);
    i++;
}

for (int j = 0; j < i ;j++)
{

    Enqueue(numbers[j], start, end);

}
```

};

Thanks to BLUEPIXY

Comment: you thanked @BLUEPIXY then did not follow the information he gave that this line: `numbers[i] = atoi(&c);` is wrong.